# custom image in UIPicker

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to implement an image in a UIImagePicker that has only one component. I add an uimageview and a uilabel.  The catch is that the first row should NOT have an image as well as the 3rd row which I believe I have done right. My problem is that the images for each row are different so to solve this I have put them into an array of images and then based on what row is being passed in, I display the image. However; it is not working for me and seems to display the same image over and over. Can anyone tell me why? Thanks in advance!

```
imageNames= [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"9_stars.png", @"8_stars.png",@"7_stars.png",@"6_stars.png",@"5_stars.png",@"4_stars.png", nil];
```

/

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
    forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {

NSString *imageName= [imageNames objectAtIndex:theRow];
NSLog (@"the image name is %@", imageName);
NSLog (@"the current count is %d", theRow);

if(component == 0)
{
    if (row == 0 || row == 17)
    {

        UILabel *channelLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-80, 0, 320, 60)];
        channelLabel.text = [currentLottoNames objectAtIndex:row];
        channelLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        channelLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        channelLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
        channelLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        channelLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        channelLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake (0,1);

        UIView *tmpView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 60)];

        [tmpView insertSubview:channelLabel atIndex:0];
        return tmpView;

    }
    else {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        UIImageView *temp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];        
        temp.frame = CGRectMake(120, 15,70, 27);

    UILabel *channelLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-80, 0, 320, 60)];
    channelLabel.text = [currentLottoNames objectAtIndex:row];
    channelLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    channelLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    channelLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
    channelLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    channelLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    channelLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake (0,1);

    UIView *tmpView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 60)];
   [tmpView insertSubview:channelLabel atIndex:0];
    [tmpView insertSubview:temp atIndex: 1];
    return tmpView;
}
   }
 }
```

**EDITED CODE**

```
 -(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
    forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {

NSString *imageName= [imageNames objectAtIndex:row]; // This is where the issue is I believe. What do I use to go through the whole image array?
NSLog (@"the image name is %@", imageName);
NSLog (@"the current count is %d", row);

if(component == 0)
{

       UILabel *channelLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-80, 0, 320, 60)];
        channelLabel.text = [currentLottoNames objectAtIndex:row];
        channelLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        channelLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        channelLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
        channelLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        channelLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        channelLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake (0,1);

        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        UIImageView *temp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];        
        temp.frame = CGRectMake(120, 15,70, 27);

    UILabel *channelLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-80, 0, 320, 60)];
    channelLabel.text = [currentLottoNames objectAtIndex:row];
    channelLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    channelLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    channelLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
    channelLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    channelLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    channelLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake (0,1);

    UIView *tmpView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 60)];

    [tmpView insertSubview:channelLabel atIndex:0];
    [tmpView insertSubview:temp atIndex: 1];
    return tmpView;
 }
 }
```

Comment: Make sure you understand the idea and consequences of reusing views as that is were your code fails.

Comment: Can you provide some exact feedback please?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is "theRow" - its not even defined in this method. You should just put a placeholder string in the array - that is at position 0 and 17 just put @"". Now you can use "row" to index into your array and all will be well.

EDIT: So your code implies you have 18 rows, want to show an image in most rows, but do something different for rows 0 and 17. Thus, you need an array of size 18.

```
imageNames= [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
@"", // row 0 unused
// 1 - 6
@"9_stars.png", @"8_stars.png",@"7_stars.png",@"6_stars.png",@"5_stars.png",@"4_stars.png", nil]; 
// 7 - 12
@"9_stars.png", @"8_stars.png",@"7_stars.png",@"6_stars.png",@"5_stars.png",@"4_stars.png", nil]; 
// 13 - 16
@"9_stars.png", @"8_stars.png",@"7_stars.png",@"6_stars.png",
// 17
@"" // not used
// keep adding
nil];
```

The concept is to insure that you always have the same number of objects in the array as you have rows.

You can add an assert at the start of this method:

```
assert(row < [imageNames count]);
```

which will cause an exception if what you believe to be true turns out not to be.

Comment: Thank you David. I did as you suggested However I am a little confused with "row". It appears it is not equal to the current row selection in the picker. For example if I nslog the value of "row", the very first row should return "0". Instead it returns "2" or sometimes "3". Do you know why this is? Thanks in advance

Comment: theRow is not even declared or set in the code above - maybe you are confusing "row" and "theRow" in your code? "theRow" is set elsewhere???

Comment: I was referring to the parameter being passed in "row". I made the change to my code to use "row" instead of theRow. Is this not what you suggested to use to index my array? Thanks again

Comment: The picker can ask for a view in any order it wants - that is not unusual for Apple. What I'm talking about is "(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
    forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {

NSString *imageName= [imageNames objectAtIndex:theRow];" where you are using "theRow" but there is no such variable defined (this from your code above).

Comment: I have removed the code theRow, let us forget that ever existed. But for sake of explanation I had it defined in my header file as NSString and then in - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
   didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
 theRow= row;
}
But this obviously is not correct. So my question to you is can I use the parameter "row" for my array from the method "(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view? And if not do you have any other suggestions? Thank you

Comment: So we cycle back - the way to just use it is to add @"" where you have special cases, so that there is a true alignment between "row" and "objectAtIndex". This is a common technique to avoid having to modify the index to retrieve some value. So you skip 0 and 17 - for both of those indexes in the array, you just need a placeholder so the other indexes are proper. No more adding or subracting from the row to find the index.

Comment: I think I'm not explaining my issue well so I have edited my question so that you may see the code. The problem is that I do not know what to use to go through the array itself. I do not understand how "row" from the method parameters works since it does not begin from '0'. Thanks